# How to Flexbox 3 children, one left and two to the right

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there any way I can accomplish the following example in flexbox with three children?

[image]

I currently use the following code:

```
# Slim
.container
  .children
  .children
  .children

# SASS
.container
   display: flex
   flex-wrap: wrap
   align-items: center

  .children
    flex-basis: 50%
```

Is there any way to do get the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use that HTML structure you can do this with Flexbox if you set fixed height on parent element and use `flex-direction: column` with `flex-wrap: wrap`. So if you make first element 100% of height other two elements with break to right side.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.children {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  flex: 1;
}
.children:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 2px solid #44C0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you could wrap other `2 .children divs` inside with `another .container` then yes you could try it as shown below:

```css
#box{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background:#ccc;
  text-align:center;
}
#box > .b1{
  flex:1 1 0;
  background:#f22;
  margin-right:10px;
}
#box > .box1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex:1 1 0;
}
#box > .box1 > .b2{
  flex:1 1 0;
  background:#f2f;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
#box > .box1 > .b3{
  flex:1 1 0;
  background:#ff2;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="b1">1</div>
  <div class="box1">
      <div class="b2">2</div>
      <div class="b3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `columns` instead of `flex` will make it much easier for you.

**Example Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container {
  width: 30vw; margin: 16px;
  column-count: 2; column-gap: 0; 
}
.container > div { 
  background-color: #44a; border: 2px solid transparent;  
  width: 15vw; height: 15vw; 
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.container > div:first-child { width: 15vw; height: 30vw; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

*Note 1: Using relative dimensions will keep it responsive as well.*

*Note 2: You may use a transparent border and change size to increase / decrease the gaps.*